# Branch of mathematics that performs arithmetic on 3-dimensional geometric shapes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computational-mathematics

I am trying to solve a computer modeling problem that involves decomposing a random geometry into a set of primitives and am looking for the name of a branch of mathematics that helps me do so.

As a simple two-dimensional example, a regular hexagon can be decomposed into six identical triangles. In three dimensions, a Rubik's cube can be decomposed into its 3 x 3 x 3 = 27 smaller cubes. However, there will never be a unique solution--for example, the same cube can be decomposed into a set of geometries that are not self similar [e.g. (2 x 2 x 2) + (3 x 3 x 1) + (3 x 2 x 1) + (2 x 2 x 1)].

I assume that there must be some branch of mathematics that involves decomposing an N-dimensional object into a set of N-dimensional smaller objects--can somebody tell me what this branch is called?

I hope this is a bit clearer (?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Minkowski sums" (of convex objects) is a good point of departure.

Comment: Hi, try looking into [polygon triangularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).